# Architecture design: how web-tier knows when worker-tier is done processing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture

I'm building a small application for educational purposes using Amazon AWS.
The web application has two parts:

1. A form for uploading an image.
2. A grid showing all thumbnails of uploaded images.

### The flow of the application:

1. Users opens the web page.
2. Users chooses an image to upload.
3. An AJAX request to the web-tier for generating a pre-signed S3 URL is sent.
4. Upon receiving the URL, an AJAX PUT request is initiated and the image is uploaded directly to S3.
5. Upon upload completion, S3 sends an SQS queue message with the image's key.
6. One of the workers receives that message and creates a thumbnail.
7. Upon image process completion, worker uploads the thumbnail to the S3.

This figure illustrates the above:
[image]

---

Now, the web-tier uses a `db.json` file for keeping the links to all existing thumbnails. Using that file, the client-side web page renders all the thumbnails in the grid.

The problem is, how would the web-tier know when to update the `db.json` containing the link for the new thumbnail?

Ideally, the web-tier would accomplish the following:

1. Refresh the `json` only when needed (if the web-tier refreshed the `json` then it must have been modified).
2. Serve the **updated** `db.json` once it's updated (if a thumbnail was added on time `x` and another user requested the web page on time `x+1`, then the users is aware of the new thumbnail).

### Few approaches:

1. For every `index.html` request, list the S3 bucket and serve the latest thumbnails (violates item 1 from previous section).
2. List the S3 bucket on interval basis (violates both items).
3. Set timer once a pre-signed URL was requested and assume that the worker is done processing the new image upon timer's ringing (this is not even a solution for two main reasons; the web tier has more than 1 instance, the timer might ring before processing is done).
4. Using S3 Events and setup a lambda expression that sends a `HTTP GET` request to a special endpoint on my web-tier (also not a solution, as this request will be directed from the load-balancer to a single instance, what about the other instances?).

---

I have no idea how to solve this problem.
What do you suggest I do?

### Edit

As this is an educational exercise, DB services are out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit ridiculous, with the notion of storing everything in a JSON file that us continuously being updated, but the solution seems obvious enough... another S3 event notification.

Anytime you have a system that hands you the magical gift of events, relieving you of having to poll anything, you'd be remiss to overlook the value that brings.

If each web server keeps it own copy of the json file and needs to update it, that's easily solved, too.

S3 event fires on thumbnail creation (S3 notifications can match prefixes rather than be for the whole bucket) > S3 event publishes to SNS topic > SNS topic fans-out to multiple SQS queues, one for each web server.   A process on the web server subscribes to that server's queue with a single thread, and each time a message comes in, the json file is modified on that server by the local worker.  Each server gets a copy of each notification.

I have an old legacy system where web site template changes (not code, just templates) are made live by committing the template changes to subversion, followed by `svn up` on the servers.  Because this subversion repo exists for the purpose, the web servers read the templates directly from he check out directory.  Strange as it sounds, it's served well for many years.  I recently enhanced it by setting up an arrangement reminiscent of what's described above, but without S3.  The "post-commit hook" fires a shell script on the subversion server when anything is committed.  This, in turn, publishes a message about the changed file to an SNS topic, which fans out to several SQS queues -- one for each web server, and a simple script on each server listens to the SQS queue for that server. One listener, one thread, for each server, so there are no concurrency issues.  The listener, it runs "svn up" on the newly-committed file, deletes the queue message, then listens for the next one.  Real-time event fan-out, why not?

Comment: I can't see how your solution can be scalable? Can the number of SQS(one for each process) be scaled out depending on the number of web servers? Can the SNS automatically be configured to fan the message to all new SQS queues too? Moreover, this seems to be an overkill in my opinion. How does the process on each web server samples the queue? It has no sqs daemon as its not a worker environment.

Comment: It's perfectly scalable.  When a new web server comes online, it creates a queue for itself and and subscribes that queue to the SNS topic. Something has to be running on each web server if you want each one to have a local copy.  You could use SNS directly and deliver topic notifications to each server with https, but that fails because the requests have to be processed in series.  But, as I suggested, the hypothetical "problem" proposed here is a ridiculous one with artificial constraints.  Nobody in their right mind would try to solve the issue here by maintaining a static index file.

Answer (score 1):

Is the db.json file stored on one of the web servers? How can you coordinate updates to the db.json file across multiple web servers? How can you prevent multiple worker servers from updating the db.json file at the same time and stepping on each other?

I would suggest storing the existence of the thumbnails somewhere other than a flat file. DynamoDB would be a great place to store this. PostgreSQL or one of the MySQL flavors on RDS would also work.

To serve the JSON data to the UI that contains the list of thumbnails I would create a dynamic page that queries the database and renders JSON data. This would also allow you to implement things like paging of the data, which will be a requirement once your set of images gets very large.

To prevent the web tier from being overloaded by requests for the JSON data I would place a CDN such as CloudFront or CloudFlare in front of the web tier. To prevent the database from being overloaded with queries for the thumbnail list I would implement a caching layer (Redis) between the web tier and the database.

Comment: In this exercise, DB services are out of the scope. Of course the `json` cannot be stored in each of the web servers - that's one of my conclusions.
I thought of storing the `json` file in S3 too and set a lambda function to update it once a new thumbnail is put in the bucket. This way the web servers won't be dealing with the `json` at all, they will just put a reference to it on the client-side code.

Comment: @johni in that design there is still no way to prevent multiple instances of the Lambda function from running at the same time and blowing away each other's updates to the `db.json` file. DB services may be "out of scope" for this exercise, but they are the only way to build this correctly without lots of concurrent update issues.

Comment: Also, if you are doing a homework assignment that has some sort of restrictions like "can't use a database" then you should state that in the question.

Comment: Isn't it possible to disable concurrent executions of a lambda function?

Comment: @johni no that's not possible at all.